# Error sending & receiving data map via jQuery's getJSON with struts2 json plug-in

Tags: jquery, json, struts2, jsonplugin

Preamble:

I'm using the Struts2 JSON plug-in, and it all appears to be configured properly.

I can receive JSON data from my json action and that works fine.

I can also send simple data via getJSON (just a string, a map with only simple string key:value pairs) also without error. They set the appropriate properties on my Action as I would expect.

**However**, when I try to send a map that contains either an array, or another map, I start to get errors on the server side.

**Updated** and cleaned up to show what I'm trying a bit better, with hopefully less clutter.

Unfortunately, I've moved on from the test stuff I was writing so things have changed a fair bit.
Meaningful Slice of Action:

```
private Map<String, String> viewedEntries;  
public Map<String, String> getViewedList() {
    return viewedEntries;
}
public void setViewedList(Map<String, String> viewedList) {
    this.viewedEntries = viewedList;
}

public String submitViewedPDIJson() {
    if (viewedEntries!=null && viewedEntries.size()>0) {
        for (String key: viewedEntries.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("viewedList[" + key + "] = " + viewedEntries.get(key));
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("No viewedList values.");
    }
    return Action.SUCCESS;
}
```

Action Definition:

```
    <action class="com.xxxxx.broker.struts.actions.PdiAction" method="submitViewedPDIJson" name="submitViewedPDIJson">
        <result type="json">
            <param name="noCache">true</param>          
        </result>
    </action>
```

Javascript:

```
    $("#submitViewed").submit(function(){
            $.getJSON('pdi/submitViewedPDIJson.action', {"viewedEntries": {"broker1": true, "broker6": false}},function(data) {
                console.log('submitted viewed entries map');
            });
            return false;
    });
```

Server-Side Error:

```
15:00:12.505 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-9] WARN  c.o.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack - Error setting expression 'viewedEntries[broker1]' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@cc831a'
ognl.OgnlException: target is null for setProperty(null, "null", [Ljava.lang.String;@cc831a)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2219) ~[xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:na]
    at ognl.ASTProperty.setValueBody(ASTProperty.java:127) ~[xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:na]
```

It's possible I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here, and this is the wrong approach. What I'm hoping to do is have my Map on the server populated by the data sent by the getJSON call. And possibly some other data as well. It seems to work fine for simple stuff, but mixing in maps-within-maps, etc, doesn't work.
If this is not the correct approach, I would appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Can you post the action in full? Or even better a minimized version of the action that showcases your issue.  I've used the struts2-json plugin for some time and have found it very dependable.

Comment: Updated the original question to hopefully better show my problem/error with less clutter, a bit more code to look at.

Comment: It's a good idea to show the entire action, or prune and test a reduced action (then post that) because it is hard for someone who has an error to discern what parts are at fault.  That said... does your constructor instantiate a HashMap and assign that to viewedEntries?

Comment: I didn't, but adding one doesn't seem to matter.
I'm beginning to wonder, is this really trying to set 'viewedEntries' as a map of string pairs, or is it trying to set a more complex data model? ie: viewedEntries as an object, with it's own properties that cannot be found?
Or something like that?
The 'viewedEntries[broker1]' in the error logs makes me curious about what it's really trying to do.